# How do I log a defect against Google's gmail app?

Tags: iphone, gmail

I'd like to lodge a defect against Google's gmail iphone app. Does anyone know where the public bug tracker is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Google has a public bug tracker. However, there is an unofficial one available at [code.google.com/p/googlebugs](https://code.google.com/p/googlebugs/). I did some extra looking, and there doesn't seem to be anything like Apple's own [bug reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com) or the [community-driven one](http://www.openradar.me/).

Thankfully, Gmail.app has a built-in mechanism to send feedback with. Starting with your inbox view, open the menu by tapping on the menu icon in the top left. Then:

`Tap the gear icon > "Help and Feedback..." (see picture) > "Send Feedback"`

This will provide you with a form to send feedback to Google.

[image: gmail.app feedback]